# How to create a LinearLayout with wrap_cotent in java code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What is the java programmically equivalent to create the following `XML` file:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <RelativeLayout />
</LinearLayout>
```

I try doing this, but some how the `LinearLayout` scretch to `MATCH_PARENT`

```
// child is the RelativeLayout in the above example:
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams childLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parent.addView(child, -1, childLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LayoutParams parentLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parent.setLayoutParams(parentLayoutParams);
```

And then add this to the screen

```
outerlayout.addView(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutParams` you are setting are for the `RelativeLayout`, not for the `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` is using `MATCH_PARENT` as default parameters, I would bet. When you add `parent` to the `Window` or root `ViewGroup`, you should create a proper set of `LayoutParams` and specify `WRAP_CONTENT`.